# How to create a web app that checks availability of train tickets in real time?

Tags: web-applications, real-time

I'm about to start a final cs50 project and now is looking for an idea for it.
So, loser to a point.
Goal:
Create a web app (with limited features) that notifies a user when the desired tickets are available for a certain date and destination.

Questions:

- How difficult is it to write for a beginner?
- What should I consider before I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. can be easy if you find some "user friendly getting started" tutorial and follow it step by step..

   2. if you want to interact with a big data flight platform (skyscanner for example) you need to use the API they expose to the web.
      probably you need to study [this documentation](https://partners.skyscanner.net/affiliates/travel-apis/) and implement it in your application.. read it and find what requirement it need to work, then project your app starting to that requirement (to respond your second question)

Comment: Thank you Mike for the answer, but what if this platform is not as open as skyscanner and does not provide their API at least publicly. Is it still possible to figure it out without their 'permission'?

Comment: i don't think so, access to someone data without permission is called hack and is not really good for the law.. Anyway you have to find the right API not exclusively SkySkanner (in fact they have **flights** tickets and not **train** tickets... it was a mistake :/ ). With the right API you can access to the data you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Mike that answers my question in full, appreciate!

Comment: happy to help you!